# Oracle sql recursive

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-query, connect-by

I have the following table:

```
+----+-----------+------+
| ID | Parent_ID | Name |
+----+-----------+------+
|  1 | null      | A    |
|  2 | null      | B    |
|  3 | null      | C    |
|  4 | 1         | D    |
|  5 | 4         | E    |
|  6 | 2         | F    |
+----+-----------+------+
```

And I need to get table like this:

```
+----+------+
| ID | Name |
+----+------+
|  1 | A    |
|  2 | B    |
|  3 | C    |
|  4 | AD   |
|  5 | ADE  |
|  6 | BF   |
+----+------+
```

I checked the ORACLE related questions here, but I did't find anything useful.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Nor have you stated what you have attempted and where it's gone wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
SELECT ID, REPLACE (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (NAME, ' '), ' ')
      FROM TABLE1
START WITH PARENT_ID IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = PARENT_ID
  ORDER BY ID;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/47c53/8)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WITH b(ID, Parent_ID) AS (
  -- Anchor member.
  SELECT ID,
         Parent_ID
  FROM   DataTable
  WHERE  Parent_ID IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  -- Recursive member.
  SELECT a.ID,
         a.Parent_ID
  FROM   DataTable a, b
  WHERE  a.Parent_ID = b.id
)
SELECT ID,
       Parent_ID
FROM   b;
```

Comment: You are not concatenating the IDs - you need something like `WITH b( ID, path ) AS ( SELECT ID, NAME FROM DataTable WHERE Parent_ID IS NULL UNION ALL SELECT a.ID, b.PATH || a.NAME FROM DataTable a INNER JOIN b ON a.Parent_ID = b.ID ) ...`